# Using setTimeout for Discord bot response delay and custom "is typing"

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to delay my bot's response time with setTimeout, and input a custom "(botname) is typing". Here is my current code. I have tried a few ways to code the setTimeout adapted from other needs, but have not seen one for this type of scenario.

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4J0c.png)

```
client.on('messageCreate',   (Message)    =>     {
if (Message.content.includes("I don't know"))
{ 
Message.reply({
   content: "Do we need to go over the mechanics again?"
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the code as a code block, not links to images. Also why do you have 2 messageCreate events? All of your logic should be handled in one event

Comment: I started this yesterday, and have never touched code before. The 2 events worked, so I rolled with it. I can input the code block.

Comment: Checkout [TextChannel#sendTyping()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=sendTyping)

Answer (score -2):

You can implement a setTimeout anywhere, really, you simply need to wrap the supposed content of it into a function, and wrap the function into a setTimeout, like so for example

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
 console.log('before timeout')
 setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('after timeout')
 }, 1000) // waiting time in seconds * 1000 (in ms)
})
```

This will print 'after timeout' a second after you sent the message, while printing 'before timeout' immediately, you can replace the console.log with anything else, and you can modify the waiting length by modifying the number 1000!

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for

Comment: It does tackle one of the problems they described.